# Continuous integration tool

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a trivial continuous integration tool using node.js to learn the platform. So far it can download a project from Github, and unzip it into a random folder in a predefined dropfolder. But I'm pretty inexperienced in pure JavaScript and loosely typed languages in general and the code that I write looks very chaotic to me. Below are the relevant parts of my tiny application (full source on [GitHub](https://github.com/andreysarafanov/SimpleCI)):

**config.json**

```
{
  "port": "8081",
  "dropDownFolder": "E:\\dropdown",
  "loggers": [
    {
      "type": "consoleLogger"
    },
    {
      "type": "consoleLogger"
    },
    {
      "type": "fileLogger",
      "logFile": "log.log",
      "errorFile": "error.log"
    }
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
      "name": "SimpleCI",
      "urlToListen": "/simpleci",
      "copyTo": "E:\\dropdown",
      "dataSource": {
        "sourceType": "github",
        "user": "andreysarafanov",
        "repository": "SimpleCI",
        "branch": "master"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Logging/loggerBuilder.js**

```
var config = require("./../config.json");
var FileLogger = require('./fileLogger');
var ConsoleLogger = require('./consoleLogger');
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = function buildLogger(callback) {
  //console.log("start building loggers " + config.logger);
  var loggers = [];
  _.each(config.loggers, function(logger) {
    if (logger.type === "fileLogger") {
      loggers.push(new FileLogger(logger.logFile, logger.errorFile));
    }
    else if (logger.type === "consoleLogger") {
      loggers.push(new ConsoleLogger());
    }
    else {
      callback("Logger type \"" + logger.type + "\" is not supported.");
    }
  });

  return {
    log: function log(message) {
      _.each(loggers, function (logger) {
        logger.log(message);
      });
    },
    error: function error(message) {
      _.each(loggers, function (logger) {
        logger.error(message);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

**Logging/fileLogger.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var endOfLine = require('os').EOL;
module.exports = function fileLogger(logFile, errorFile) {
  return {
    log: function log(message) {
      fs.appendFile(logFile, buildString("debug", message));
    },
    error: function error(message) {
      fs.appendFile(logFile, buildString("error", message));
    }
  };
}

function buildString(type, message) {
  var time = new Date();
  return type.toUpperCase() + ": [" + time.getYear() + "." 
    + time.getMonth() + "." + time.getDate() + "] - " + message + endOfLine;
}
```

**Logging/consoleLogger.js**

```
module.exports = function consoleLogger() {
  return {
    log: function log(message) {
      console.log(buildString(message));
    },
    error: function error(message) {
      console.error(buildString(message));
    }
  };
}

function buildString(message) {
  var time = new Date();
  return "[" + time.getYear() + "." + time.getMonth() + "." 
    + time.getDate() + "] - " + message;
}
```

**index.js**

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var _ = require("underscore");
var config = require('./config.json');
var dataLoader = require("./DataLoaders/dataLoader.js")
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var LoggerBuilder = require('./Logging/loggerBuilder');

var app = express();

var logger = LoggerBuilder(function(err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
})

_.each(config.builds, function(build) {
  app.get(build.urlToListen, function(req, res) {
    console.log("A request for build " + build.name + " has been received");
    var id = uuid.v4();
    dataLoader.downLoadDataForBuild(build.dataSource, id, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        res.send("Error: " + err);
      }
      else {
        logger.log("downloaded data for build " + build.name + " to subdirectory " + id);
        res.send("Success");
      }
    })
  })
});

app.listen(config.port);
```

I can configure multiple loggers in `config.json` and the output will be written to all of them (in this case - twice to the console and to the file). The code seems to work as expected, but I ended up relying on string constants(`"fileLogger"` and `"consoleLogger"` for logger type, the names of the fields in `config.json`), and the code that initializes logger objects looks boilerplate to me. How would you refactor the code to make it more ordered and less error-prone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logger configuration doesn't seem bad. It's a little verbose, but it is open to further extensions if those ever come along. I don't know your requirements, but if you're only ever going to have one file logger and optionally a console logger, you could change your list into an object like so:

```
loggers: {
  "console": true,
  "file": {"logFile": "out.log", "errorFile": "err.log"}
}
```

But having a list is just fine. Not knowing anything else about your requirements, I would leave it the way it is.

The thing that really sticks out to me in your code is the use of a callback as a parameter in `loggerBuilder.js`. Since this function is not asyncronous, I would ditch the callback and either log the error directly to the console or just throw the error and let it break the build. If you really want to provide a mechanism for reporting configuration errors to the user, then rename "callback" to something akin to "errorHandler". The use of the name "callback" usually signifies a function that will be executed once and only once, will be executed when the function has completed, and will not return a completed value but instead pass the value as an argument to the function.

Also, I find it surprising that you do not log the time to the output of the file or console logger. Not a big deal of cource, it just stuck out.

Comment: Danny, thanks! I don't have any requirements at all and just thought that having a list of loggers in config is the most extensible of the simple solutions. Guess I'll refactor the callback in `loggerbuilder.js`. Do I get it right that code like `if (logger.type === "fileLogger")` is pretty much normal in javascript? For example, I'd definitely call it smelly and eagerly refactor it into a enum or at least some constant string in C#.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov, You're absolutely correct, a check like that is normal in javascript. If your node version supports it, you could define a `const` for the different types, but it would still be a string in the end. And I'm with you, if I was in java land I would make this into an enum in a heartbeat. :)